# Is there a function that acts like a camera in the viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, tracking

The example is a car on a highway.  Keyframed at 2 points and a camera parented to the car.  When viewing from the camera the car is in frame.   When viewing from the viewport the car flies by.

Is there a way to make the viewport follow the car like the camera?  A function that allows the viewport to act like a camera. That can track an object as if it were parented to that object. I noticed that would be very helpful when trying to animate a driver in the car, etc..

This would be a great feature I think if not already implemented.

Answer (score 2):

AH *View Lock to Active* under the *View* -> *Align View* menu.  Ok, I think that's the answer.

[image]

There is also an eye-dropper tool in the N-panel.

[image]